# How to clone repository from Bitbucket to the same location I uploaded it into Bitbucket?

Tags: git, clone

I have the following project:

[image]

I right-clicked in that folder ,I clicked GitBash here, made the necessary commands to commit and push that project into BitBucket where it looks like this:

[image]

And the commit looks like that in Commits section:

[image]

I want to make some changes in the project in picture 1 using Visual Studio, but I'm not sure if these changes will be successful, so if they aren't I want to reverse the changes to the "First Commit" and the changes to take effect in the files from picture 1. I know that it's done by cloning. But can I clone in the same directory (from picture 1) I uploaded the project from and how? There are few examples in internet that does cloning but they seem to me that they aren't for what I want them for and I fear I will broke my project, commit etcetera. If I change something in my project from picture I and the change is successful I want to commit giving some name of the change but if I continue doing some changes and I broke something I want to go to the previos step and the reverting to take efect also in picture 1 files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you open your project from VS (without making a new clone), and do the changes you want. If you don't like them and want to revert (Assuming you have not pushed anything yet), you can execute the following:

```
git add -A             /* Adds all changes you made */
git reset 2f6b3e6      /* Resets back to the first commit */
git reset --hard       /* Removes all changes */
```

If you already pushed changes to your repo and want to revert, then you should look at git revert.